# How do I fix error in .xts subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am facing the following issue :

```
Error in `[.xts`(merge.xts(AF.PA, ACA.PA, BN.PA, ORA.PA, RUI.PA, SAN.PA,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
De plus : Warning messages:
1: In merge.xts(AF.PA, ACA.PA, BN.PA, ORA.PA, RUI.PA, SAN.PA, VIE.PA,  :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
2: In merge.xts(AF.PA, ACA.PA, BN.PA, ORA.PA, RUI.PA, SAN.PA, VIE.PA,  :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
```

While doing :

```
DataList <- merge.xts(AF.PA,ACA.PA,BN.PA,ORA.PA,RUI.PA,SAN.PA,VIE.PA,WLN.PA,ALCHI.PA,FGR.PA,FP.PA,TKA.DE,"CLNK-B.ST",MCPHY.PA)[, ListeData]
```

Where `ListeData` is :

```
 ListeData <- c("AF.PA.Close","ACA.PA.Close","BN.PA.Close","ORA.PA.Close","RUI.PA.Close","SAN.PA.Close","VIE.PA.Close","WLN.PA.Close","ALCHI.PA.Close","FGR.PA.Close","FP.PA.Close","TKA.DE.Close","CLNK-B.ST.Close","MCPHY.PA.Close")
```

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

**EDIT**

```
> head(merge.xts(AF.PA,ACA.PA,BN.PA,ORA.PA,RUI.PA,SAN.PA,VIE.PA,WLN.PA,ALCHI.PA,FGR.PA,FP.PA,TKA.DE,"CLNK-B.ST",MCPHY.PA))
           AF.PA.Open AF.PA.High AF.PA.Low AF.PA.Close AF.PA.Volume AF.PA.Adjusted ACA.PA.Open ACA.PA.High ACA.PA.Low ACA.PA.Close ACA.PA.Volume
2011-04-11     11.440     11.550    11.310      11.330      1657258         11.330    11.40629    11.50259   11.17999     11.34370       5091912
2011-04-12     11.310     11.660    11.300      11.560      3772391         11.560    11.26185    11.38222   11.17037     11.26666       7021608
2011-04-13     11.620     11.695    11.515      11.655      1834744         11.655    11.32925    11.45925   11.17999     11.30999       6261396
2011-04-14     11.635     11.655    11.540      11.630      1157155         11.630    11.26185    11.31481   10.94407     11.04518       9524086
2011-04-15     11.675     11.675    11.520      11.565      1585345         11.565    11.06444    11.09814   10.79962     10.83814       8623416
2011-04-18     11.565     11.595    11.160      11.215      1856826         11.215    10.78518    10.82370   10.22185     10.30851      19475785
           ACA.PA.Adjusted BN.PA.Open BN.PA.High BN.PA.Low BN.PA.Close BN.PA.Volume BN.PA.Adjusted ORA.PA.Open ORA.PA.High ORA.PA.Low ORA.PA.Close
2011-04-11        8.234507     46.770   46.83000  46.13499      46.495      1862796       34.21361      15.790       15.98     15.785       15.870
2011-04-12        8.178584     46.270   46.64500  46.15000      46.255      1890901       34.03701      15.725       15.79     15.625       15.690
2011-04-13        8.210040     46.330   47.04499  46.30500      46.835      1576105       34.46380      15.755       15.79     15.690       15.695
2011-04-14        8.017809     47.305   48.02000  47.17000      47.755      4491311       35.14079      15.655       15.71     15.570       15.620
2011-04-15        7.867519     47.845   48.74500  47.72000      48.595      4235853       35.75891      15.650       15.67     15.540       15.645
2011-04-18        7.483054     48.430   48.59500  47.66000      48.030      3284665       35.34316      15.710       15.74     15.315       15.370
           ORA.PA.Volume ORA.PA.Adjusted RUI.PA.Open RUI.PA.High RUI.PA.Low RUI.PA.Close RUI.PA.Volume RUI.PA.Adjusted SAN.PA.Open SAN.PA.High
2011-04-11       6777650        8.444629    20.21842    20.55532   20.11663     20.16510         59661        14.22550       50.55       51.57
2011-04-12       7909760        8.348848    20.16510    20.22085   19.68279     19.69975        132405        13.89722       51.20       51.77
2011-04-13       5178599        8.351508    19.85002    20.16510   19.85002     19.96878         99773        14.08700       51.15       51.61
2011-04-14       6207744        8.311601    19.97121    19.97121   19.75550     19.84518         39204        13.99981       51.01       51.25
2011-04-15       8052940        8.324903    19.83791    19.97121   19.76519     19.92273         28790        14.05452       51.03       52.00
2011-04-18      10946669        8.178572    19.99544    20.03180   19.38952     19.43072         80558        13.70743       51.94       52.10
           SAN.PA.Low SAN.PA.Close SAN.PA.Volume SAN.PA.Adjusted VIE.PA.Open VIE.PA.High VIE.PA.Low VIE.PA.Close VIE.PA.Volume VIE.PA.Adjusted
2011-04-11      50.55        51.27       3100546        34.69120      22.105      22.340     21.960       22.315       1634842        13.86625
2011-04-12      51.10        51.19       4309238        34.63707      22.230      22.285     21.950       22.000       2065622        13.67052
2011-04-13      51.09        51.43       2535415        34.79946      22.000      22.300     21.965       22.205       1235612        13.79790
2011-04-14      50.72        51.17       2491698        34.62353      22.120      22.190     21.870       21.960       1021874        13.64566
2011-04-15      51.00        51.86       4291534        35.09042      21.780      22.165     21.770       22.050       1228735        13.70158
2011-04-18      50.58        50.78       4240343        34.35965      21.650      21.970     21.255       21.380       2270933        13.28525
           WLN.PA.Open WLN.PA.High WLN.PA.Low WLN.PA.Close WLN.PA.Volume WLN.PA.Adjusted ALCHI.PA.Open ALCHI.PA.High ALCHI.PA.Low ALCHI.PA.Close
2011-04-11          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
2011-04-12          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
2011-04-13          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
2011-04-14          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
2011-04-15          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
2011-04-18          NA          NA         NA           NA            NA              NA            NA            NA           NA             NA
           ALCHI.PA.Volume ALCHI.PA.Adjusted FGR.PA.Open FGR.PA.High FGR.PA.Low FGR.PA.Close FGR.PA.Volume FGR.PA.Adjusted FP.PA.Open FP.PA.High
2011-04-11              NA                NA      43.600      43.810      43.41       43.490        174411        32.49482     43.115     43.245
2011-04-12              NA                NA      43.130      43.695      42.81       42.825        157637        31.99795     42.700     42.765
2011-04-13              NA                NA      42.955      43.640      42.81       43.415        107992        32.43879     42.175     42.510
2011-04-14              NA                NA      43.200      43.320      42.81       43.130        113405        32.22584     41.935     41.965
2011-04-15              NA                NA      43.145      43.190      42.60       42.960        131400        32.09882     41.720     41.860
2011-04-18              NA                NA      42.990      42.990      41.80       41.950        105751        31.34417     41.580     41.580
           FP.PA.Low FP.PA.Close FP.PA.Volume FP.PA.Adjusted TKA.DE.Open TKA.DE.High TKA.DE.Low TKA.DE.Close TKA.DE.Volume TKA.DE.Adjusted
2011-04-11    42.740      43.005      3237285       23.63081      30.235      30.620     30.210       30.400       1664569        28.67990
2011-04-12    41.770      41.940      7334198       23.04561      30.085      30.090     29.255       29.405       2341040        27.74120
2011-04-13    42.020      42.050      3768822       23.10605      29.730      30.500     29.680       29.815       3332431        28.12800
2011-04-14    41.260      41.640      5010563       22.88075      29.720      29.980     29.610       29.900       1909963        28.20819
2011-04-15    41.265      41.675      6472160       22.89998      29.895      30.075     29.580       29.710       2084037        28.02894
2011-04-18    40.340      40.660      8417195       22.34226      29.505      29.520     28.350       28.545       3077434        26.92986
           X.CLNK.B.ST. MCPHY.PA.Open MCPHY.PA.High MCPHY.PA.Low MCPHY.PA.Close MCPHY.PA.Volume MCPHY.PA.Adjusted
2011-04-11           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
2011-04-12           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
2011-04-13           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
2011-04-14           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
2011-04-15           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
2011-04-18           NA            NA            NA           NA             NA              NA                NA
```

[image]

Comment: Does simple `merge.xts(AF.PA,ACA.PA,BN.PA,ORA.PA,RUI.PA,SAN.PA,VIE.PA,WLN.PA,ALCHI.PA,FGR.PA,FP.PA,TKA.DE,"CLNK-B.ST",MCPHY.PA)` work ?

Comment: sure, but I just want `Close` ..

Comment: Could you provide us the output of `head(merge.xts(AF.PA,ACA.PA,BN.PA,ORA.PA,RUI.PA,SAN.PA,VIE.PA,WLN.PA,ALCHI.PA,FGR.PA,FP.PA,TKA.DE,"CLNK-B.ST",MCPHY.PA))` ? thanks

Comment: @BastienDucreux Please see the edit

Comment: Yes then the problem comes from "CLNK-B.ST.Close" as it doesn't exist

Comment: @BastienDucreux It does exist looks the edit i added screenshoot, should I delete `"` ?

Comment: I think that's the problem because if you look at the merged object, this column does not exist, if you suppress quotes in merge, I hope it should be ok

Comment: @BastienDucreux when i delete quote it returns : `objet 'CLNK' introuvable` I think it does not understand `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListeData <- c("AF.PA.Close","ACA.PA.Close","BN.PA.Close","ORA.PA.Close","RUI.PA.Close","SAN.PA.Close","VIE.PA.Close","WLN.PA.Close","ALCHI.PA.Close","FGR.PA.Close","FP.PA.Close","TKA.DE.Close","CLNK.B.ST.Close","MCPHY.PA.Close")

DataList <- merge.xts(AF.PA,ACA.PA,BN.PA,ORA.PA,RUI.PA,SAN.PA,VIE.PA,WLN.PA,ALCHI.PA,FGR.PA,FP.PA,TKA.DE,`CLNK-B.ST`,MCPHY.PA)[, ListeData]
```

Comment: `subscript out of bounds` and the name is CLNK-B.ST and not CLNK.B.ST ..

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated and this code works for me

Comment: And in ListeData why do you let . and not -

Comment: Because R automatically replaces dash by . in colnames

Comment: You're welcome, sorry for my hesitations !